# Download File from AWS S3 Access Denied

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use Amazon web service to store files for my iOS App.

Here's the code I am using to download the file stored on AWS S3

I added the following to the appDelegate

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
   initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast2
   identityPoolId:@"us-east-2:3764e0f9-khu97-4844-b9f7-57defdfjv8b8b"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast2 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

Then in my class I used the following to download the object. Kindly note that no encryption is applied to the object and all permissions are unblocked for the bucket

```
- (void)downloadImageToAWS{

// AWS Configurations
    AWSS3DownloadHelper *aws = [[AWSS3DownloadHelper alloc] init];
    aws.bucket = @"my-sample-bucket-002";
    aws.key = @"photo-sam-002.jpg";

    // AWS progress block
    aws.progressBlock = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityTask *task, NSProgress *progress) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"progress.fractionCompleted %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
        });
    };

        // AWS completionHandler
        [self addAWSDownloadComplitionHandler:aws];

    // Update UI if job / task can upload a file on AWS S3
    [self successfulDownloadOfAWSS3ByCompletionHandler:aws.completionHandler withProgressBlock:aws.progressBlock];

    [aws downloadAWSFile];
}

- (void) addAWSDownloadComplitionHandler:(AWSS3DownloadHelper *)aws {
    // Create instance to View Controller
    NSLog(@"addAWSDownloadComplitionHandler");
    aws.completionHandler = ^(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask *task, NSURL *location, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Unsuccessfully downloaded error %li", (long)[error code]);
            NSLog(@"Unsuccessfully downloaded error %@", [error description]);
        }
         else if (data) {
            NSLog(@"data %@", data);
            }
        });
    };   
}


- (void) successfulDownloadOfAWSS3ByCompletionHandler:(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock)completionHandler withProgressBlock:(AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock)progressBlock {
NSLog(@"successfulDownloadOfAWSS3ByCompletionHandler");
AWSS3TransferUtility *transferUtility = [AWSS3TransferUtility defaultS3TransferUtility];
[transferUtility enumerateToAssignBlocksForUploadTask:nil downloadTask:^(AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadTask * _Nonnull downloadTask, AWSS3TransferUtilityProgressBlock  _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable downloadProgressBlockReference, AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock  _Nullable __autoreleasing * _Nullable completionHandlerReference) {
    NSLog(@"taskIdentifier %lu", (unsigned long)downloadTask.taskIdentifier);
    
    *downloadProgressBlockReference = progressBlock;
    *completionHandlerReference = completionHandler;
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        });
    }];
}
```

Although I have put all permissions to allow. Block all public access is turned off, I keep getting the following error:

```
    Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={Server=AmazonS3, Error={
    Code = AccessDenied;
    HostId = "SJABFLSKBtprmLRaHLjjockzjfubejlakhipjaKDNSAFJLB4ViE=";//Changed
    Message = "Access Denied";
    RequestId = jabduw2dhC6WCT;//changed
}, Transfer-Encoding=Identity, Content-Type=application/xml, Date=Wed, 29 Dec 2021 09:33:06 GMT, x-amz-request-id=2TJSHCJ2ASTC6WCT, x-amz-id-2=Fbg2cDXwU5wLgQLHbGtprmLRaHLjjocvZzCcUNfMrSpT5Oiwl3LjEkpPQ2OBzLmBrKXnrwq4ViE=}
```

I have applied all suggestions in this video:
[Why am I getting an Access Denied error from the Amazon S3 console while I modify a bucket policy? - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KE5sp5-4Czk)

Trying the following command on the cloud shell didn't show any error:

```
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket name>/<key> /tmp/localfile
```

Comment: You indicated that you applied suggestions from a YouTube video that's related to Access Denied when modifying a bucket policy, but that seems to be completely unrelated to your problem. Unless you really know what you're doing here, you shouldn't have made any of those changes.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for your comment, indeed aws environment is totally new, and I'm not sure I'm on the right track, therefore any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: Please try to refrain from asking whether readers need to know more information in the post - it just clutters the post, and readers know to ask this anyway.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your feedback. Kindly refrain from editing my posts for extremely silly details, like removing hy, or thank you, or if further information are needed. We are humans and not machines at the end of the day, and these minor details does not negatively affect the content in any way. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @coder. A version of your request has been considered by the community many times, and while it is understood, it has broadly been denied. Don't take it personally! I would discourage you from feeling strongly about it. However, if you really want to stick to your guns, could you [ask a question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)? If you do so, let me know, and perhaps I can post an answer.

Comment: (It is possible that such a post would be regarded as a duplicate, but that is not a terrible thing on Meta - at least one would have an answer, even if it maintains the inertia of pre-existing community decisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Cognito as the credentials provider. As I understand it, even for public buckets, if you access through API, you need to setup proper IAM roles and permissions. That means assigning the **IAM roles** with S3 access to the **authenticated identities** inside the **identity pool** in **Cognito**.

Or, you have to pass the `no-sign-request`. At least in CLI you have to do so. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/.

But if you access using URL, with public buckets, you will be able to get the objects.

Comment: Indeed my mistake was that I was assigning IAM user all the permissions while I should have done so for IAM role. Thank you for your kind advice.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's rule out coding.  Try to access the file natively using the AWS CLI.  Just a straight up `aws s3 cp s3://<bucket name>/<key> /tmp/localfile`

If this works, you've got a code issue, and we continue checking.  If it does not work, you may have a permissions issue.

The 2nd thing to check - are you using encryption?  Chances are (from my experience) that while you may have permissions to access the S3 bucket, you may not have permissions to access the encryption key, so the access denied you're getting is actually coming from KMS.  You may need to allow the right to decrypt the KMS key.

Comment: First of all thank you for your suggestion, I am not using any kind of encryption so we can rule that out, second, I wanted to try the cloud shell command but got the following: CloudShell is not available in Middle East (Bahrain). Please select another region.

Comment: Do you think the region might the reason of Access Denied, I have chosen the region were I am in, should I choose differently? knowing that I wish the file to be access worldwide.

Comment: Switch your region to us-east-1, and try CloudShell again.  The fact that CloudShell isn't available in Bahrain shouldn't be an issue.  On my own system, I have the AWS CLI installed, so no need to use CloudShell.  Just be careful though - when you use CloudShell, it will inherit the permissions you are logged on with, not necessarily the permissions you are assuming to use from your app.  So when you do manage to fire up cloud shell, you should update your access keys to be similar to the ones you're trying to use from your app.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Bahrain region, but I do know that it needs to be enabled (as in it is not enabled by default).  It is possible that region could be an issue, so try to force the region in your code (I'm familiar with boto3 in python, and you can specify the region).  Another possibility is that the endpoint for Bahrain may not be enabled.  Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande-manage.html

Comment: I have enabled the region, but from your previous reply I notice that there must be an access key to be used, I am very knew to the aws environment do you think you can send a documentation that shows how to set it. I have used this gitHub project in my app, and thought it might be enough: https://github.com/dimitardanailov/objc-aws-playground

Comment: I have created an identity pool id and updated the one in the project, before using it. but there was nothing related to access key.

Comment: I have made some edits to the question, I wish you would check them.

Answer (score 1):

In cognito Identity pool you can specify two IAM Roles (even more, but lets focus on default two):

- Unauthenticated role - the role assigned to user which is not logged in to Identity Provider
- Authenticated role - the role assigned to authenticated user

Default roles created by Cognito don't provide access to S3 buckets - you have to modify policy and add missing permissions (i.e. s3:PutObject, s3:GetObject, s3:ListBucket)

If your bucket is encrypted with KMS key, your role policy or key polisy must allow kms actions (i.e. kms.Encrypt, kms:Decrypt, kms:generateKeyData)

Try to invoke sts getCallerIdentity action in your app and check returned identity, it should return Authenticated role ARN.
If so, add missing permissions to access S3 bucket and KMS key to returned role policy.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very instructive and I'm sure will be very useful for others and I wish I can award it more than one vote, but it's the other answer that in fact targeted my problem exactly.